# Xcode 4 - Header file not found when including 3rd party static lib

Tags: ios, xcode4, nocilla

I am trying to check out [Nocilla](https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla) but I can't seem to get my test target to build when I include it. I cloned the Nocilla repo and built the static lib (targeting simulator) from source. I am linking the nocilla static lib to my test target.

I have all of Nocilla's public headers included in my project but for some reason Xcode complains that it cannot find headers which are located in the same relative location from which they are being referenced.

Trying to run my tests results in the following compilation error:

> 'LSHTTPRequest' file not found

Nocilla provides installation instructions which include using CocoaPods. I am not interested in using CocoaPods. Does anyone have any clues for me as to why my tests cannot find these header files? Am I missing a build step to ensure they are copied to the test execution location?

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Did you add your headers to `User Header Search Path`?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the *User Header Search Paths* for the project that wants to include the static library headers:

[image]

The exact location of the header files will vary on the relative location between the two projects of course.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'other' project. I have 1 project with two build targets. Once of which is the test target.

Comment: No i have the same problem with my test-target and a static library.